# E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Type constructor: GHC.Prim.Addr

Tags: plutus

Has anyone encountered such an issue?

Validator works fine and cborHex is generated when "`writeSerialisedScript`" run in cabal's repl. But when building with `cabal build app`, the following error is thrown:

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Type constructor: GHC.Prim.Addr#
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Prim.Addr#
Context: Compiling data constructor type: Data.ByteString.Internal.PS
Context: Compiling type: Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString
Context: Compiling data constructor type: Model.TypeD.TypeD
Context: Compiling type: Model.TypeD.TypeD
Context: Compiling type: Model.TypeD.TypeD
                         -> Model.TypeDAction.TypeDAction
                         -> Plutus.V2.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext
                         -> GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling type: Model.ColonySettings.ColonySettings
                         -> Model.TypeD.TypeD
                         -> Model.TypeDAction.TypeDAction
                         -> Plutus.V2.Ledger.Contexts.ScriptContext
                         -> GHC.Types.Bool
Context: Compiling definition of: Validators.TypeD.mkColonyValidator
Context: Compiling expr: Validators.TypeD.mkColonyValidator
Context: Compiling expr at "ship-shift-0.1.0.0-inplace:Validators.TypeD:(171,8)-(171,50)"
```

Running `cabal configure -f defer-plugin-errors` before building seems to work, but I get the following linker warning:

```
/nix/store/jfkmqz20q8fsaqizcml86adxqyzlwllx-binutils-2.38/bin/ld: warning: type and size of dynamic symbol cardanozmapizm1zi35zi4zm8209ae821a2638d4c1d3e2b96141de65263d756436220f129fed7d2f300d13d8_CardanoziApiziSerialiseTextEnvelope_zdfIsStringTextEnvelopeDescr_closure are not defined
```

I've tried troubleshooting by commenting out lines to find the culprit to no avail.

Definition of `Model.TypeD.TypeD` is as follows:

```
type TypeA = (TypeB, Value)

data TypeB = A
            | B
            | C
            | D
            | E
            deriving (Show, Generic, Prelude.Eq, ToJSON, FromJSON)

PlutusTx.makeLift ''TypeB
PlutusTx.makeIsDataIndexed ''TypeB [('A, 0), ('B, 1), ('C, 2), ('D, 3), ('E, 4)]

data TypeC = TypeC
    { y :: !Rational
    , z :: !Address
    } deriving (Prelude.Show, Generic, Prelude.Eq, ToJSON, FromJSON)

PlutusTx.makeLift ''TypeC
PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''TypeC

data TypeD = TypeD
    { 
      a  :: !BuiltinByteString
    , b  :: ![PaymentPubKeyHash]
    , c  :: !Integer
    , d  :: ![TypeB]
    , e  :: ![TypeA]
    , f  :: !(Maybe TypeC)
    } deriving (Prelude.Show, Generic, Prelude.Eq, ToJSON, FromJSON)
    
PlutusTx.makeLift ''TypeD
PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData ''TypeD
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues.
I don't understand the Core to PLC plugin enough to explain why this happens, but I am fairly sure this is related to using types on-chain that have a *strict* field of type `BuiltinByteString`.

So removing the `!` in front of field `a` in `TypeD` should avoid running into this error.